# Jmeter record failed

Tags: jmeter, sharepoint-2013

I have a Windows server 2012 where jmeter 4 is installed. I try to record browser action using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder but I'm facing a problem. I try to access to a Sharepoint site using NTML authentification on another Active Directory.

My Test Script recorder is set to use the port number 8080 and HttpClient4.
My proxy browser is set to use the port 8080 on localhost.
In the system.properties file, I've set my firm proxy like this :

```
http.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
http.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
https.proxyHost=your_corporate_proxy_host
https.proxyPort=your_corporate_proxy_port
```

When I'm going on my SharePoint Site, I've to enter my credentials but then I got an error "Error Connexion reset". I can see that the action are recorded and the response of the request is "401 Unauthorized".

I'm sure that my credentials are good.

Jmeter give this message : Out of sequence NTLM response message

Do you have any idea to resolve this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: might be a work around , please have a look  
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996226/5717031

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and put your credentials along with domain name there
2. Instead of using *system.properties* file try passing proxy settings via [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) like

   ```
   jmeter -Hyour_corporate_proxy_host -P your_corporate_proxy_port -u your_username -a your_password
   ```
3. And last but not least you can record your scenario using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) which doesn't require any extra configuration in terms of proxy setup, authorization, SSL certificates, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I can already tell you that the first and the second point of your list doesn't work. I will try the third one.